# New Line character \n in SQLite concatenate

Tags: sqlite, newline

I know that, in some Programming language, if you do something like:

```
'This is on first line \n This is on second line'
```

Then it will display properly like this:

```
This is on first line
This is on second line
```

When I concatenate a string in a SQLite database

```
SELECT *, [FIELD1] || '\n'  || [FIELD2] from TABLE
```

(where [FIELD1] = This is on first line
[FIELD2] = This is on second line)

it displays as such:

```
This is on first line \n This is on second line
```

Is there a reason that it isn't displaying the \n characters properly?

Answer (score 49):

SQL has no backslash escapes.

You can generate a newline in a string by writing it directly in the query:

```
SELECT [Field1] || '
' || [Field2] FROM MyTable
```

or use a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```
SELECT [Field1] || x'0a' || [Field2] FROM MyTable
```

or use the [char function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#char):

```
SELECT [Field1] || char(10) || [Field2] FROM MyTable
```

Comment: `char()` works only in fairly recent SQLite, which may not be present if you're on a really old long term supported distro like CentOS.

Comment: @DamianYerrick indeed. Changelog for [2013-03-18 (3.7.16)](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_16) says "Added SQL functions unicode(A) and char(X1,...,XN)". "Enterprise Linux" 6 comes with sqlite version 3.6.20.

Answer (score 3):

Try `char(13)` (if you want to see it in Windows notepad).

```
select col || char(13) from mytable
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right...