# SQlite replace '\n' to newline

Tags: sqlite, newline

I have `\n` in my database after importing from Mysql. How can I replace '\n' to be a real new line?

I tried

```
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '\n', "\n")
```

in several variations but without success.

Comment: similar question: [New Line character \n in SQLite concatenate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930865/new-line-character-n-in-sqlite-concatenate)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE cy_prod SET text = replace(text, '\n', '
')
```

made the trick

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```sql
UPDATE table SET column = replace(column, '\n', char(10));
```

ASCII char code 10 is the UNIX newline character.