# Line Breaks in MySQL Column

Tags: sqlite, line, break

I have a mySQL column called `description` and I have several sentences in this column. For example: "John ran down a hill. He was tired. John went to get water." I would like a line break after each sentence so that it outputs like:

`John went to get water.`

`He was tired.` 

`John went to get water.`

I'm using a SQLite DB Browser (http://sqlitebrowser.org/). I thought I could do line breaks with: "John ran down a hill. \n" but unfortunately it outputs the \n as well as the "". Can anyone help me with these line breaks? Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to replace '. ' (period space) with '. ' and \n outside the quotes so it gets appended as a value and not a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [New Line character \n in SQLite concatenate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930865/new-line-character-n-in-sqlite-concatenate)

Comment: SQLite or MySQL? It's tagged both.

Comment: SQLite. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't have string escaping logics. You have to concatenate the `newline` char using another way, like the `char(10)` function or typing it in exadecimal: `x'0a'`. Remember that the character `10` is the `newLine` for windows architectures.

Just use a query like this (to update all the rows):

```
update tabel_name set "description" = 
replace("description", '.', '.' || x'0a')
```

If you want to edit a specific row add a WHERE clause:

```
update tabel_name set "description" = 
replace("description", '.', '.' || x'0a')
WHERE "rowid" = 1
```

The `||` is the concatenation operator in SQLite.

Comment: Will this work for only one row? I am a bit confused as to how to use char. Is this a field type? I am currently using text (I was using varchar but line breaks didn't work, text didn't work either)

Comment: this query will update all of your rows (you have only to change the table name). If you want it to work on specific rows you should add a WHERE clause

Comment: hm.. so assuming I have a rowid column with id numbers I would do:

`update table_name set "description" where rowid="1" = 
replace("description ", '.', '.' || x'0a')`


I am a bit new so apologies.

Comment: Thank you. My last question: so I would put my sentences in the `replace ("John ran down the hill. He needs water.", '.', '.' || x'0a')` correct?

Comment: no, double quotes are used to specify field names, you should use `replace ('John ran down the hill. He needs water.', '.', '.' || x'0a')`. But I though that the value was already inside the field

Comment: Yes. I was just going to add more. Hm.. for some reason I executed the SQL code but unfortunately it is still the same. Do you have any other tips?

My executed code is:

update `Main Database` set "description" = 
replace("description", '.', '.' || x'0a')
WHERE "rowid" = 1

Comment: If Main database is the table name you should wrap it around double quotes: "Main database"

Comment: Unfortunately I did not solve this issue yet. The concatenation clause did not work in SQLite Manager unfortunately so I am unsure what has happened. I may end up going another route to mitigate this.